# Understanding the effects of deleting pg_wal in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Our database crashed lately due WAL files filling up space. I figured out the source of the issue after the fact, but for a quick solution since we already had a separate/recent backup of the database, I deleted the `pg_wal` folder.

From what I understand, this can cause some issues with `pg_basebackup`. Majority of research I've done has found that deleting `pg_wal` can result in a corrupted database.

What I don't understand is in what situation would things be corrupted?

If I delete `pg_wal` and then take another fresh `pg_basebackup`, wouldn't I still be able to restore from that backup? or does `pg_basebackup` rely on older wal entries to be generated properly? And if that is the case, how is it any different than restoring from `pg_dump` and then running `pg_basebackup`?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the transaction log, which is contained in `pg_wal`, you have deleted an integral part of your database. You won't be able to start your database, and you might as well delete the rest of the data directory and restore your backup.

A specialist can probably still salvage most of the data, but particularly when the database had crashed, there will be data loss.

**Never, ever, delete `pg_wal` or any other part of the data directory.** The exception are the log files, which are inside the `log` subdirectory of the data directory if you chose the default location.

Comment: Can you define integral? My understand of the `pg_wal` files were they were used to catch your database up to date from the point of your last backup. So assuming any changes were made from the point of my last `base` backup, they would be lost.

But assuming I didn't care about those changes, is there still harm in just taking a new base_backup without restoring from a `pg_dump`? 

I was able to restart the database fine and it currently has built in processes to catch up on missing data, so I'm trying to understand what people really mean when they say "corrupted".

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, I'm just not clear how restoring from pg_dump and then doing a new base_backup would be any different than just running a new base backup on the current database.

Comment: @NicoleStaline pu_dump can be plain text format, which can be restored via psql. while pg_backup, you can't do that in psql. for me I feel like it's more setup to restore from pg_basebackup.

Comment: @Mark To clarify,I meant even if we restore from a `pg_dump`, that is going to restore to a database with empty an `/pg_wal` and then we will start running our `pg_basebackup` again which seems like the exact same thing to me as just not restoring from `pg_dump` and running a new `base_backup` on the current `/data` directory.

Comment: Look closely: `pg_wal` is never empty, even in a newly created database cluster. I cannot explain the whole design behind a transaction log in a comment or an answer. You obviously don't understand them yet, which is ok: read up on the concept in the PostgreSQL documentation.